# Bsh - new line not interpreted with printf and "echo -e"

Tags: bash, printf

I would like to generate 2 values columns (actualy `(x,y)` for `y=x^2 function`).

So I did under `Bash`:

```
echo $(for((i=0;i<100;i++)); do printf "%3d %3d\n" $((i)) $((i*i)); done)
```

But I get a single row with `(i,i*i)` sequence, not 2 columns.

I tried to add `"-e" option` for `echo`, but this doesn't work too.

If someone had a trick, this would be fine.

Comment: You're... echoing the output from printf?

Comment: Go figure... Remove the `echo $(` and the ending `)`.

Comment: That's a common antipattern actually.  See [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).

Comment: Thanks ! didn't know that was useless